# Dynamically adding class to readonly field in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

HTML

`<input id="TextBox" type="text" runat="server" readonly="readonly" />`

JS

```
function MyFunct(sender, args) {
                var TextBox = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox.ClientID %>');
                if (true) {
                    TextBox.value = "somevalue";
                    TextBox.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
                    $('#<%= TextBox.ClientID %>').addClass("disabledTb");
                }
                else {
                    TextBox.value = "";
                    TextBox.readOnly = false;
                    $('#<%= TextBox.ClientID %>').removeClass("disabledTb");
                }
        }
```

CSS

```
.disabledTb {
            background-color: rgb(235, 235, 228);
            color: rgb(84, 84, 84);
        }
```

The readonly propery is working, I had to change the input from an asp:TextBox to a standard HTML textobx because otherwise the value wouldn't be retrieved to server side and I didn't want to use a hidden field.

However, now the  .disabledTb class is not applied anymore. the rest of the code works fine, and changing

```
var TextBox = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox.ClientID %>');
```

to

```
var TextBox = document.getElementById('#<%= TextBox.ClientID %>');
```

causes a null reference seen in the console

**Update**

I forgot to say I'm using a Master Page, so the id ends up to be something like 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox'

**SOLUTION**

Turns out I was referencing the wrong control. Fixing that solved my problem.
The rest of the code is totally usable.

referencing a control with **#** in the call to the ID is required for jQuery functions but not plain Javascript. `<%= TextBox.ClientID %>` will work even for HTML inputs where the runat attribute is set to server. This will provide the correct ID when using master pages.

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly set the input's ID as "TextBox" but you're trying to retrieve it as `<%= TextBox.ClientID %>`, use "TextBox" as the ID (and better, give a more meaningful name to the ID).

ClientId is used for ASP .net controls which have it's ID autogenerated by the ASP runtime.

Comment: I've forgot to say I'm using a Master Page, so the id ends up to be something like 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox'

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I was referencing the wrong control. Referencing the correct control in the script solved my problem. The rest of the code is totally usable.

Referencing a control with `#` in the call to the ID is required for jQuery functions but not plain Javascript. `<%= TextBox.ClientID %>` will work even for HTML inputs where the runat attribute is set to server. This will provide the correct ID when using master pages.